# Sum and total per row for calculated column in Power BI/DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to sum 3 columns. This DAX for a calculated column sums all rows in the dataset rather than summing per row.

[image: Total per row for calculated column]

Using a measure with the same DAX works, except the total is wrong....

[image]

How do I get the correct sum per row and total?

Answer (score 1):

Calculated columns have a row context, but no filter context.  If you want to add the current row context into a filter context, wrap your calculated column expression in CALCULATE.

> The CALCULATE function used without filters achieves a specific
> requirement. It transitions row context to filter context. It's
> required when an expression (not a model measure) that summarizes
> model data needs to be evaluated in row context. This scenario can
> happen in a **calculated column formula** or when an expression in an
> iterator function is evaluated. Note that when a model measure is used
> in row context, context transition is automatic.

[CALCULATE function (DAX)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax)

Comment: I get the same results with this...

CALCULATE(MAX(Fact_NetRevRpt[Fee])+MAX(Fact_NetRevRpt[ConsultFee])+MAX(Fact_NetRevRpt[Reimb Allow]))